# Segmentation analysis based on Likert

Tags: clustering, likert

I would like to do a segmentation analysis based on a Likert scale survey. I want to ask respondents to rate certain attributes on a scale of 5 points (not valuable at all, not very valuable, neutral, relatively valuable, very valuable), probably having 8-10 attributes in total.

Once I get all the answers, I would like to run an analysis to identify the most common types of respondents (price seekers, innovators...).

What is the exact analysis I would need to run to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Factor analysis can be an option.

Let's say you already have in mind of two common factors F1 and F2 as: price seeking and innovation. Then you can look at the sample correlation matrix to 
confirm your intuitions, that there are two groups of attributes, some high 
correlations exist within each group, and the collective meanings of attributes in each group match the corresponding factor in your mind.

I guess you can try different sets of attributes to use, and different number of common factors. In case of 2 factors and 8 attributes, you have the following representation:

$Z_1 = l_{11}F_1 + l_{12}F_2 + \epsilon_1$

$Z_1 = l_{21}F_1 + l_{22}F_2 + \epsilon_1$

...

$Z_8 = l_{p1}F_1 + l_{p2}F_2 + \epsilon_1$

Estimate the parameters.

Make appropriate rotations to make things more interpretable, ideally each attribute have one dominant loading $l_{ij}$ favoring one factor.

Estimate factor score for each person:
$(f_{11}, f_{21}), (f_{12}, f_{22}),...,(f_{1n}, f_{2n})$

People with high score on factor 1 can be grouped to the 1st group: price seeking group.

(SPSS, R and SAS should all be able to do it)

Comment: Thank you! I understand that in oder to do this you need to have a preliminary set of segments (factors), right? My objective is to identify the segments without any starting point. Say, look at all the responses (likert scale for each attribute), and then run the analysis to determine the most common patterns. After looking at those, I would decide which of them can be used as segments. Is there any way to do that? Thanks

Comment: @Dave You can pick the number of factors simply by how well the algorithm fit. You can make sure of their meaning later. But in the beginning, you can always look at the correlation matrix first to see if certain attributes are highly correlated, to help you to guess the common factors.